# Search & replace in Excel formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm making a yearly report in Excel. The report contains many references to external workbooks. When updating next year's report using this year's, I would like to change, say, all occurrences of `2018` in my formulas and references to `2019`, as the referenced workbooks would be named as thus.

However, when I select the entire sheet and do `Ctrl-H` to replace `2018` with `2019`, I am only able to change the formula in the top left cell in my selection. I selected "Look in: Formula" in the Replace options and used "Replace all", but it doesn't make a difference. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you share some sample formula with us ?

Comment: @RajeshS Sure! An example would be `=IFERROR(SUMIF('C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\week7\Deliverables\KPI Scorecard root directory\Source\01 Jan\[2018 Jan report.xls]Sheet1'!$K$1:$K$65536,"<>")," ")`

Comment: I've successfully tried Find & Replace on your formula and it's working with Lookin FORMULA option.

Comment: Are you selecting *Replace All* when doing the Find/Replace?

Comment: @davidmneedham Yes. Thanks for checking tho!

Comment: @RajeshS Thanks for the update! May I check: If there are multiple occurrences of this formula, were you able to replace all `2018` in them in one go?

Comment: I was able to replace all in one pass

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to search and replace references to other workbooks in Excel. Try the following steps to try to reproduce your error. This works for me.

Open Notepad. Paste the following:

```
"=IFERROR(SUMIF('C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\week7\Deliverables\KPI Scorecard root directory\Source\01 Jan\[2018 Jan report.xls]Sheet1'!$K$1:$K$65536,""<>""),"" "")"
"=IFERROR(SUMIF('C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\week7\Deliverables\KPI Scorecard root directory\Source\02 Feb\[2018 Feb report.xls]Sheet1'!$K$1:$K$65536,""<>""),"" "")"
```

Save as `test_book.csv`

[image: notepad save]

Open the newly created `test_book.csv` in Excel by double-clicking it.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Replace 2018 with 2019. Make sure to select *Look in | Formulas*. Click *Replace All*

[image: replace all dialog]

Excel will prompt you to confirm the location of the 2019 report files if they don't already exist, but the formula will replace regardless:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer - may I check if the formulas are entered as strings by using `""`?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the error following these steps, but I would like to avoid using `.csv` files due to formatting issues. Is it possible to do that? Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, I wasn't suggest that you use a CSV file. It was just a way to find out if it is an issue with your base Excel setup. Looks like there is some problem with the way your existing file is set up. Can you find a way to reproduce the error in a way we could replicate it?